# How to add a class to a div, make it wait a while, and then add another class to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So far I can apply a class to one div but I want it to then add another class to another div to make that show and fade in down.

http://www.penguinie.co.uk/test/

I want the first page to fade out and the about page fade in (or the projects or contact page).

```
<li><a href="#about" onclick="$('#start').addClass('fadeOutUp'); $('#about').addClass('animated fadeInDown')">About</a></li>
```

That is what I used to make the main page fade out. The class hidden is used to hide the about page until the user clicks on the about link.

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: please use something like : $('li').on('click','a', function(){})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with built-in jQuery methods [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

```
$('#start').fadeOut(500, function(){
    $('#about').fadeIn(500);
})
```

This way, #about will fade in right after #start fades out. If you want different a different animation, you can use the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to specify your animation.

You can also use the setTimeout method but as far as I can see, you want one div to disappear and the other div to appear right after. I think chaining two animations would be the better option in this case.

Also, @pszaba is right. You shouldn't use onclick attributes. You should use event handlers like the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler like this:

```
$("#about").click(function(){
    $('#start').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $('#about').fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

(This code actually doesn't make sense since the #about element is invisible so it cannot be clicked :) Just use it as a reference for your own implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for setTimeout() function :

```
$('#start').addClass('fadeOutUp');
setTimeout(function() {
   // executed after 2 seconds
   $('#about').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
}, 2000);
```

**EDIT:** but about fadeIn / fadeOut, you can also take a look on `$("selector").fadeIn("slow", function(){ /* callback here */ });`

Comment: I got the same idea of @vape after reading again the question, which is probably better for your needs